# Cython return malloced pointer from function

Tags: python, cython

I am fairly new to Cython, so this is probably fairly trivial, but I haven't been able to find the answer anywhere.

I've defined a struct type and I want to write a function that will initialize all the fields properly and return a pointer to the new struct.

```
from cpython.mem import PyMem_Malloc


ctypedef struct cell_t:
    DTYPE_t[2] min_bounds
    DTYPE_t[2] max_bounds
    DTYPE_t size

    bint is_leaf
    cell_t * children[4]

    DTYPE_t[2] center_of_mass
    UINT32_t count


cdef cell_t * make_cell(DTYPE_t[2] min_bounds, DTYPE_t[2] max_bounds):
    cdef cell_t * cell = <cell_t *>PyMem_Malloc(sizeof(cell_t)) # <- Fails here
    if not cell:
        MemoryError()

    cell.min_bounds[:] = min_bounds
    cell.max_bounds[:] = max_bounds
    cell.size = min_bounds[0] - max_bounds[0]
    cell.is_leaf = True
    cell.center_of_mass[:] = [0, 0]
    cell.count = 0

    return cell
```

However, when I try to compile this, I get the following two errors during compilation:

```
cdef cell_t * make_cell(DTYPE_t[2] min_bounds, DTYPE_t[2] max_bounds):
    cdef cell_t * cell = <cell_t *>PyMem_Malloc(sizeof(cell_t))
                        ^
Casting temporary Python object to non-numeric non-Python type
------------------------------------------------------------

cdef cell_t * make_cell(DTYPE_t[2] min_bounds, DTYPE_t[2] max_bounds):
    cdef cell_t * cell = <cell_t *>PyMem_Malloc(sizeof(cell_t))
        ^
Storing unsafe C derivative of temporary Python reference
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Now, I've looked all over, and from what I can gather, `cell` is actually stored in a temporary variable that gets deallocated at the end of the function.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cell.min_bounds = min_bounds
```

This doesn't do what you think it does (although I'm not 100% sure what it does do). You need to copy arrays element by element:

```
cell.min_bounds[0] = min_bounds[0]
cell.min_bounds[1] = min_bounds[1]
```

Same for `max_bounds`.

The line that I suspect is giving you that error message is:

```
cell.center_of_mass = [0, 0]
```

This is trying to assign a Python list to a C array (remembering that arrays and pointers are somewhat interchangeable in C), which doesn't make much sense. Again, you'd do

```
cell.center_of_mass[0] = 0
cell.center_of_mass[1] = 0
```

---

All this is largely consistent with the C behaviour that there aren't operators to copy whole arrays into each other, you need to copy element by element.

---

**Edit:**

However that's not your immediate problem. You haven't declared `PyMem_Malloc` so it's assumed to be a Python function. You should do

```
from cpython.mem cimport PyMem_Malloc
```

Make sure it's `cimport`ed, not `import`ed

---

**Edit2:**

The following compiles fine for me:

```
from cpython.mem cimport PyMem_Malloc

ctypedef double DTYPE_t

ctypedef struct cell_t:
    DTYPE_t[2] min_bounds
    DTYPE_t[2] max_bounds


cdef cell_t * make_cell(DTYPE_t[2] min_bounds, DTYPE_t[2] max_bounds) except NULL:
    cdef cell_t * cell = <cell_t *>PyMem_Malloc(sizeof(cell_t))
    if not cell:
        raise MemoryError()
    return cell
```

I've cut down `cell_t` a bit (just to avoid having to make declarations of `UINT32_t`). I've also given the `cdef` function an `except NULL` to allow it to signal an error if needed and added a `raise` before `MemoryError()`. I don't think either of these changes are directly related to your error.

Comment: Nice catch, I could probably get this to a single line using something like some equivallent memcopy I guess. However, I should've marked where it fails, and it is not this. Please see my updated question. I tried removing this logic altogether and I got the same error.

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't include this in the question - I thought it was clear that I included it, the errors would also be much different if I had forgotten to include it. Sorry for all this confusion.

Comment: I've posted a shortened version of your code that compiles fine for me. If that still doesn't work I think you need to post the complete code that's failing

Comment: @Pavlin : It's almost always worth going to the trouble of creating a [mcve].  This allows people to be clear *exactly* what you have included etc.  Do note the "Minimal" there.  In this case, your structure doesn't need more than one member.

Comment: @MartinBonner I thought my example was pretty small and clear, so I left it as-is. @DavidW I am so sorry, I was just being stupid and didn't check how I imported `cpython.mem`. I had done it using `import` whereas I should've done it using `cimport`. I guess this is one thing that will take some getting used to. Thanks so much! I was completely stumped.